# Why can't I use AWS EC2 ImageBuilder to create a RHEL based container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

In the AWS console for EC2 ImageBuilder the option to create a Container Recipe using RHEL as the base image seems to be disabled.

From EC2 Image Builder console -> Container Recipes -> Create container recipe.  The 'Base Image' section for 'Image Operating System' allows Amazon Linux, Windows, Ubuntu and CentOS to be selected.  Also listed are 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)' and 'SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES)', but both of these are disabled.

I want to use RHEL as the base for my container.  Is there something I need to do in my AWS account to make these operating systems selectable?

The console itself says that RHEL is supported, and I can't locate any documentation to say otherwise.

Comment: For me those options are grayed out for container recipes but are valid for EC2 recipes. I wonder if RHEL and SUSE are simply not supported for containers.

Comment: As a member of the RHEL team this is not expected behavior. I have let members of our cloud partner team know. If you have an AWS Rep, I would also encourage you to let them know about your situation. I’ll update this thread when I hear back.